# Selecting the row of the DataGridView which the button was clicked on

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Basically my issue is my code seems to be skipping the foreach loop I have, my aim is to get the row values on a button click from the same row, this is my code so far:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
    e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
         string userID;
         string Monday;
         string Tuesday;
         string Wednesday;
         string Thursday;
         string Friday;

         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
         {
              userID = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              Monday = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              Tuesday = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              Wednesday = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
              Thursday = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              Friday = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

              dbHandler objDBHandler = new dbHandler();
              objDBHandler.writeDB("INSERT INTO [OfficeCalendar].[dbo].[DayData]([UserID],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday]) VALUES ('" + userID + "','" + Monday + "','" + Tuesday + "','" + Wednesday + "','" + Thursday + "','" + Friday + "');", "byron");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change the `SelectionMode` of your `DataGridView to FullRowSelect`

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! - Also: Do you have any rows selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own question by changing,

the SelectionMode of your DataGridView to FullRowSelect

props to MethodMan thanks for the comment it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are allowing your user to select multiple rows at a time, there's no need to loop throught them. The `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` parameter object of the `CellContentClick` event already gives you the row number that was clicked.

```
string userID;
string Monday;
string Tuesday;
string Wednesday;
string Thursday;
string Friday;

DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
userID = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
Monday = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
Tuesday = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
Wednesday = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
Thursday = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
Friday = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

dbHandler objDBHandler = new dbHandler();
objDBHandler.writeDB("INSERT INTO [OfficeCalendar].[dbo].[DayData]([UserID],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday]) VALUES ('" + userID + "','" + Monday + "','" + Tuesday + "','" + Wednesday + "','" + Thursday + "','" + Friday + "');", "byron");
```

Also, and off-topic, your code is prompt to SQL injections; use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation.